# Does LINQ work on Index?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Lets say i have an array

```
byte[] myarr = {1,4,3,4,1,2,1,2,4,3,1,4,2};
```

myarr will be of length 13 (0-12 Index) which will also be the length of int[] val.

```
int[] val = new int[13];
```

I want to check index of myarr where its value is 4 i.e. 1,3,8,11.

Then i want

```
val[1]++;
val[3]++;
val[8]++;
val[11]++;
```

One way of doing this is using for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<myarr.length; i++)
{
   if(myarr[i] == 4)
      val[i]++;
}
```

We can use Array.indexof but it returns the first index of that value meaning that value has to be unique and my myarr has lots of same values.

Can this be done using linq?

Comment: Why would you care about LINQ? You working example is perfectly simple. Besides, I think the very best you could get from LINQ would be the actual value... you would then still have to increment it and re-assign it back to the array

Comment: The 'Q' in LINQ stands for Query. LINQ is used for *querying* data. You want to *change* data. Your for loop is the way to do this.

Comment: @GrahamClark: Possible idea for LINC? .... whos in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing in LINQ (update included):

```
myarr.Select((b, i) => b == 4 ? i : -1)
    .Where(i => i != -1)
    .ToList().ForEach(i => val[i]++);
```

Your non-LINQ version is obviously much more succinct and readable, so I think you should use that.

Comment: @w0lf: What's with -1 condition in two places?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I return `-1` instead of the indices that *do not* contain a value of `4`. On the next line, I filter out any `-1`, so I end up with a list of indices that only contain the value `4`.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal It's very likely that this can be cleaned out somehow, but I still think the non-LINQ code is better in this case.

Comment: @w0lf I know for loop is the best but right now my data is less and i dont want to write many lines for a one line answer. Thanks it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it won't be simpler. LINQ will only help you with the query part, the update part has to be done in a foo loop, but since the array contains value types you need to get indexes from your LINQ-query and not the actual values and you have won nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) to store the [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx):

```
int[] newIndices = myarr.Select((i, index) => new { Index = index, Value = i })
             .Where (x => x.Value == 4)
             .Select(x => x.Index + 1)
             .ToArray();
```

**Edit**: Finally i've understood your question ;)

```
myarr.Select((i, index) => new { Index = index, Value = i })
              .Where(x => x.Value == 4)
              .Select(x => x.Index)
              .ForEach(i => myarr[i]++);
```

Comment: Where is the `increment` part?

Comment: It creates new array rather then modifying existing `val`.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: Yes, as L.B. has mentioned my first approach was not correct since it only returns the indices. So i've added the second one(that starts with "Finally i've understood your question") that modifies the orginal array.